# Configuring custom groups in .my.cnf?

Tags: mysql, emacs, customization

How do I get emacs 'sql-mysql' (or mysql for that matter) to read a custom group from .my.cnf?

I have different options when calling mysql from the cli and within emacs, and, and I wondered if I could achieve this by using a custom group in the .my.cnf, i.e. something like:

[emacs]
options...

In general, can I ask the mysql client to read a custom group?

Cheers,
Dan.

Answer (score 2):

In general, yes, you can add custom groups to my.cnf. [This article](http://datacharmer.blogspot.com/2011/03/hidden-options-file-trick.html) explains how.